# Можно ли "заморозить" элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть список div'ов, на каждом из них висит анимация на `hover`, раз в 5 сек производится сортировка списка, в начало перебрасываются div с выставленным классом:

```
$('#list').prepend($('#list .online'));
```

если оставить мышку на первом элементе, раз в 5сек происходит сброс и возобновление анимации

можно ли как-нибудь 'заморозить' `hover` перед сортировкой, чтоб избежать 'моргания' ?

**добавил:**

пример реализации проблемного места:
https://jsfiddle.net/gwqn0cd0/

Comment: Было бы здорово посмотреть на пример, который покажет проблему

Comment: @Doofy, добавил пример

Comment: Ну теперь хоть понятен вопрос. Его нужно было сформулировать по другому. *Как оставить в той же позиции элемент, на который навели курсор*. Правильно?

Comment: @Doofy, сорри, предложенный Вами вариант не решил проблему

Comment: Так я на вопрос опирался без примера. Сейчас я тоже не очень понимаю что нужно сделать

Comment: Поставив у `.user:hover .info { transition: .0s; }` [решит](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBXsj.gif) проблему? (На гифке интервал 2 сек)

Comment: Я знаю как сделать чтобы точно не моргал, но тогда фон и текст будет либо выше человечка, либо под ним. Просто сейчас как-то странно, фон за человечком, а текст над ним

Comment: transition: .0s; - сократил время, но при большом списке ( >100)  моргание заметно

Comment: @Doofy. можно набросок Вашей задумки, на словах не очень понятно?

Comment: [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Doofy/gwqn0cd0/1/) моргает? Просто у меня через раз, то моргает, то нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42758/discussion-between-ravend-and-doofy).

Answer (score 2):

Можно приостановить анимацию

```js
function reset(e) {
  e.style = 'animation-play-state: paused';
  setTimeout(function() { e.style = ''; }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: #63AEEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 8px 4px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover {
  animation: ani 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% { background: #FF6040; }
  50% { background: #63AEEE; }
  100% { background: #FF6040; }
}
```

```html
<div onclick='reset(this)'>qeqqe</div>
```

Или через стили отключить события

[pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
function off() { $('div').css({'pointer-events': 'none'}); }
function on() { $('div').css({'pointer-events': 'all'}); }
```

```css
div {
  background: #63AEEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 8px 4px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover { background: #FF6040; }
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>

<div>qeqqe</div>

<button onclick='off()'>Отключить hover</button>
<button onclick='on()'>Включить hover</button>
```

Comment: Поясните за минус

Comment: я Вас не минусовал

Comment: @ravend, какой-то мухамор заминусил и смылся без объяснений, ладно